# Spinner not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, spinner

I have added a spinner to my screen but it does not show. Here is my code pause spinner and play spinner

```
   func pause() {
    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
}
```

Here is my restore method

```
func restore() {
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
}
```

I have declared my spinner just inside the class

```
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
```

Here is where I am calling the spinner

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

   // myarray = [""]
  // var take = NSMutableArray

    pause()
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Questions")
    query.whereKey("Level", equalTo:level)
    query.whereKey("Quiz", equalTo:quiz)
    query.orderByAscending("Ques")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")

            var i = 0;

            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    println(object.objectId)
                    let pf = object as PFObject
                    let name = pf["Question"] as String
                    ql.append(name)
                    if (flag1 == 0){
                    myarr.insert(name, atIndex: i)
                    i++;
                    }

                }
            }
            println(myarr);
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure

            println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("error", sender: self)
            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            defaults.setBool(false,forKey:"l"+String(level)+"q"+String(quiz))
            defaults.setBool(false,forKey:"l"+String(level)+"p")
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.restore()
        })

    }
    if (flag1==0){
        ques = 1
    }
    questions()
    println(ql)


    super.viewDidLoad()
```

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (probably long running) query runs as a background task so your `restore()` will be called immediately. You have to change 2 things:

1. Put your call to `restore()` within the background execution block
2. Keep "The Law" in mind: Updates to UI elements must be done in the main thread

So, for 2. you have to wrap `restore()` in the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    restore()
})
```

Comment: I added the code, still does not work, updated the code

Comment: Did you move that code block in your background block?

Answer (score 0):

Your ActivityIndicator starts with your `pause` function and stops with your `restore` function. In `viewDidLoad`, most of the work is carried out by the block you have defined, which runs in the background. The time from `pause` to `restore` will be tiny. `restore` will run long before your block finishes executing.

If you want the spinner to run until the block finshes, you need to do something like

```
println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")
restore()
```

inside your block. But, beware, I am not sure what thread your block executes on, and I am not sure if it is correct to call `restore` from a background thread. You could try it.